# Yii2 advanced template Login from Front end and redirect to Back end home page with login

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a code in the Yii2 Advanced template, here I want to make a single login page for a frontend for Users and backend for Admins. Once I have logged in from frontend then, if that was an admin then I want to redirect to backend homepage with that login and not logged in the frontend, also if that was a user then I want to redirect in frontend homepage.

Here my problem is for admin user I have redirected to backend index page but I need to log in again in the backend. Also if I used frontend for admin that account still remaining.

My siteController.php in Frontend :

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $userDetails = User::findByUsername($model->username);
        if($userDetails->username == 'admin' && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect('http://localhost/yiiadvanced/backend/web/index.php');
        } else {
            $model->login();
            return $this->redirect(array('/site/custom'));
        }
    } else {
        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The admin data and user data are on the same table.

Please, anyone, give the solution for this problem,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest adding an role column to the user table to identify which users are admin or regular users, rather than the string check of the username. Based on this role, you could change the goHome() function to redirect to the backend or the frontend page depending on the user role.

Comment: @Lisa, Right now I have redirected to backend index page based upon username. But here my problem was when redirecting again login was asked in my backend URL also. So I have to log in 2 times.

Comment: Do you maybe have a redirect to login on the backend index page?

Comment: check the user type first and them attempt to login , you are doing the wrong way

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, Thanks for point out this, But while login only I have checked the user type and attempt login. Please check the above code and is that correct?

Comment: @Lisa, Ya but if i have logged in from frontend and i have used backed home page so why asking login again in backend. Need to change any session or cookie params/values?

Answer (score 0):

"need to log in again in the backend", to distinguish frontend and backend users, you can change the session name in a config with a different name between the frontend and backend

```
'session' => [
   // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
   'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
 ],
```

Comment: @sholeh, Yes it is working once I have changed the session name in backend config file. Thank you so much but if same session name means if I log out from backend then front end also need to log out?. But it doesn't. Why? Please explain.

Comment: if you use the same session, then when you log out on the backend
  automatically on the frontend also log out

Comment: @sholeh, No it's not logged out in the frontend. If I logged out from backend and changed to frontend URL its shows with login with the same user.